# How can I test my new laptop battery without special equipment?

Tags: laptop, battery

I just bought a new battery for my Acer AO756 laptop. I couldn't find any high-capacity ones produced by my laptop's vendor, so I bought a product made by GreenCell. It doesn't seem to charge past 94% though (after this time it behaves either as if fully charged or as if it wasn't being charged at all) and I would like to test whether its storage is as good as advertised. How can I do that without special equipment?

Answer (score 0):

If your battery does not charge beyound 94%, then it is not functioning properly and you can return it to OEM. There is no need for any additional tests.

I can suggest two very basic ways to perform basic benchmark testing of laptop battery:

1. Use a laptop and a known good battery (reference) to compare against. Just charge both batteries fully and then drain them fully while mantaining identical CPU load. Measure and compare the time until batteries are fully drained. Ensuring that consumption during both tests is the same is the hardest part of the test.
2. Another option is to discharge the battery through the resistor and monitor current and voltage.  This requires basic knowledge of Ohm's law, few resistors, Voltmeter, Current meter and laptops' power consumption specs. Be careful though - you need to know what you are doing.

As you can see both methods are relatively cheap and simple. Make your choice